# why images in the Images.xcassets are not displayed?

Tags: ios, image

There are some image resources in my **Images.xcassets**. Recently they cannot be displayed in the app when testing in the iPhone/iPad devices.

I guess they are not copied to the Bundle when build and package. Then i check the 
**Copy Bundle Resources** in **Build Phases**. The **Images.xcassets** is in here.
One weird situation is it works well in simulators, but failed in the real devices. For a clean test, every time i will delete the app and then run again.

Some of snippets are as below:

```
   UIButton *button_Share = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13,33,64,20)];
    [button_Share setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [button_Share setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [button_Share setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"share_btnM@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button_Share addTarget:self action:@selector(click_Share) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [imageview_ButtonBg addSubview:button_Share];

    UIButton *button_AddTo = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(112,33,97,20)];
    [button_AddTo setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [button_AddTo setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [button_AddTo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add_cart_btnM@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button_AddTo addTarget:self action:@selector(click_AddToCart) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [imageview_ButtonBg addSubview:button_AddTo];

    UIButton *button_Buy = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(243,33,64,20)];
    [button_Buy setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [button_Buy setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [button_Buy setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buynow_btnM@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button_Buy addTarget:self action:@selector(click_Buy) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [imageview_ButtonBg addSubview:button_Buy];
```

images in the image set are as below:
[image]
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Recently they cannot be displayed in the app" How are you trying to display them?

Comment: @matt by imageNamed with file name to display it.

Comment: Very strange... You are spelling the name the same as the name of the Image Set? Including the capitalization of that name?

Comment: @matt yes, it's strange... i thought maybe this is the bug of xcode, but i cannot figure out why. the name in the project is Images.xcassets, i will update the question.

Comment: I'm asking about the image name...

Comment: @matt image names are the same, because it works well in the simulator. almost all the images in the image set are disappeared.

Comment: Can you show your code, and show a screen shot of an image set that is not working?

Comment: @matt Add some snippets and the related images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have not understood the principle of asset catalogs. They give to their assets the names of the image sets. You no longer use the old size-based image names. That is the whole point of asset catalogs! You use *one* name and the right asset is chosen for you, appropriate to your hardware.

Thus, for example, this call is wrong:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"share_btnM@2x.png"]
```

Your image set is called *share_btnM*, so you would say simply:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"share_btnM"]
```

You need to go through all your code, find all your `imageNamed:` calls, and fix that everywhere. Then your images will work.

Comment: You are correct. But could you kindly explain why simulator works?

Comment: :) Because the old bundle-based images are still present in the simulator build. If you clean your caches and reset your simulators, as I explain [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073), your simulators will stop working too!